# Continuous-time & Discrete-time kalman filter(KF)

Tags: kalman-filter

I seek the general difference between continuous time and discrete time Kalman filter(KF). I want to design the continuous-time transition model &discrete-time measurement model KF and discrete-time transition model & discrete-time measurement model KF, say EKF. So here the concern is regarding the transition model dynamics described by the non-linear state space differential equation, $\dot x(t) = f(x(t))+w(t) $  -> (1),
where ($w(t)$) is noise which can be considered as input. In my knowledge, once I integrate the equation the Eq (1) numerically using the RK45 method with varying step size control in order to get the state x from $\dot x$ in discrete form, then I can implement discrete form EKF, but I have got the wrong result after integrating continuous-time nonlinear differential equation to use discrete EKF. But when I used the continuous Riccatii equation for state covariance prediction, it worked well (before I used similarity transformation for the covariance prediction or propagation for discrete EKF). So my question is, will I get the result in continuous or discrete form once I integrate Eq 1 (continuous-time differential equation) using any numerical integration method? I thought it would be discrete, but not. So, then if the results from the integration are in the continuous form, do I need to use any discretization method like Euler or an analytical solution like $x(k+1) = e^{A\Delta t}$for $\dot x(t) = A\cdot x(t)$, where A is the jacobian of $\dot x(t) = f(x(t))$ in order to use discrete Kalman filter.

Also to add, irrespective of continuous or discrete time, we have to integrate the differential equation in order to implement it in the digital computer, but now I am confused about the domain of the integration result whether it is in the continuous or discrete domain.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.
Best
Hashir

Comment: You said that you're getting the wrong result after integrating---can you post an example of the code that you're using?